# With xcode/swift how do I change the color of my SKSpriteNode that is a black image to white?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have created a game with an SKSpriteNode that is a black image and when the user touches the screen I would like for the SKSpriteNode to change to white.

I have tried to use this:

```
sprite.color = .whiteColor()
sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1
```

And it does nothing. I have also tried something like:

```
let colorize = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.whiteColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1, duration: 5)
sprite.runAction(colorize)
```

But this just makes the sprite fade to white and then back to black.

How do I make my black sprite image turn white and stay white when the user touches the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the `color` property of a sprite with a black texture will have no effect. Also, setting a sprite's `color` property to `.whiteColor()` will have no effect, regardless of the sprite's original color. That said, there's at least one way to transition the color of a sprite from black to white.

First, start with a sprite with a white image (you can the change the color of the black image to white in an image editing app):

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "whitebird")
```

Next, set the sprite's `color` property to black and the `colorBlendFactor` to 1

```
sprite.color = .blackColor()
sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
```

Finally, in `touchesBegan` recolor the sprite from black to white by changing the `colorBlendFactor` from 1 to 0:

```
let recolor = SKAction.colorizeWithColorBlendFactor(0, duration: 2)
sprite.runAction(recolor)
```

Comment: Is there a way (methods) to give a `SpriteNode` any color you want? I'm really struggling to understand the concept behind why changing the color of `sprite` works sometimes, but wouldn't other times. It probably has to do something with the color choice? I hope you can get back to me

Comment: @Sharukh you can set a sprite's color to red with `sprite.color = .redColor()` or blue with `sprite.color = .blueColor()`. To see the color change, however, you must also set the color blend factor to a non-zero value, such as `sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1.0`.

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work. I would usually say `sprite.color = UIColor.redColor()`,with the `colorBlecdFactor` set to `1.0`, and it wouldn't change the color

Comment: @Sharukh did you set `sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1.0`. If you don't include the sprite's name, the blend factor is applied to the scene. Also, the color only affects non-black pixels.

Comment: yes i do include that, and it doesn't change the color. What is non-black pixels?

Comment: @Sharukh what color is the sprite?

Comment: Red color sprite, and I'm trying to change it to green, blue, or yellow

Comment: Got it working. I made my sprite fully white initially and it changes to every color. But, what did you mean by non-black pixels though?